# Get current datetime in gridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

now here is a problem with me that how can I enter the current date in gridview. And when i sell the stock I can add it in TOTAL but when the next day will come the records will insert in next row then i want to add the sell record of the day agian in total for that day only in other words day by day record of sell stock will add in "total"(only for sell stock of the day).

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want an entry in your gridview on a per day basis? Do you want the value in the "date" column to default to the current day?

Comment: yes sir you are getting it right. i really mean it.

Comment: where is the data source for the gridview coming from?

Comment: from the database and its enterd by the another form thats name "transaction" which will count the TOTAL the openstock will add from this form.

Comment: Seeing some of your source code will help but I assume that when you press the "add open stock" button it calls a method that sets some values.  In that method you can set the value of the "date" to be today.

Comment: yes thats absolutly right sir.

Comment: can you edit your post an include that source code?

Comment: its a textbox where i will enter the INT value thats the open stock for the day and thenclick the button that will insert the record in the table(Gridview) and when i sell the stock for that day from the another form i will insert the record fro the TOTAL thats the sell stock of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to set the default value in the database column to be todays date for all new records.

Another possibility is to set a default value on the `DataTable` with something like: `<<DataTable>>.Columns["Date"].DefaultValue = System.DateTime.Today`. The disadvantage of the default value on the `DataTable` is you need to be careful to update the default value if the application runs over midnight

Comment: today is any kind of default value or any method,keword or somthing else? Would i hv to cast it in ToString() or not?

Comment: I assumed that your "date" column is of type DateTime.  if it is of type string the yes you would need to add a ToString. You can use `ToShortDateString()` if you are only interested in the date part.

Comment: the today help me alot and i got wat i want nad i just make the Date column to primary so now user can only make entry once for whole day thanks @Indigo.